# AngularJS Thermal Printing

Tags: javascript, thermal-printer

currently i made a cloud web based application that wants to be able print a receipt using a thermal printer, now i'm using ESC/POS M58-LL Thermal Printer, which has Bluetooth and USB interface..

When i try to print direclty from chrome it shows a weird and long code printed out, not my html.. and it seems that this kind of printer doesnt recognized html to be printed out..

So is there any way that's make me able to print using this printer, when the user access it from browser on pc and from mobile device by using javascript or angularJs ?

Thankyou

Comment: have you checked printer from any other web page? according to https://github.com/receipt-print-hq/chrome-raw-print I believe there could be issues related to raw/not-raw printing mode

Comment: @skyboyer yes i was try to find another solution but still cant find out, i also ever visit the link you give above but it seems not become a solution, since i also targeting mobile user as well for accessing the web platform

Comment: does printing work for any _other_ site?

Comment: @skyboyer nope, it wont work properly for web based printing.. but if it using native app, then it working properly

Comment: so the issue is not related to programming at all. you cannot communicate driver from JS code so there is no way to fix that at this level. try installing that addon I've given a link to. Maybe it help. if it does not you will have to switch onto native app instead of web-based